# bibliography by chapter

Tags: bibliographies, chapters

i'm using book as document class and i'm trying to create the bibliography at the end of the document. I've tried to use `\begin{thebibliography}{1}`but the result is not compatible with the one that i want. 
In particular i would like to have a division by chapter and the "tag" should not be (for example) [1,2,3,etc.] But (for the first chapter)[1-1,1-2,etc] (for the second) [2-1,2-2,etc.] and so on. 
Can you help me?

Here is an example.

Chapter 1

[1-2]....

[1-2]...

Chapter 2

[2-1]....

[2-2].....

etc.

Comment: Package `chapterbib` for example? And providing a document would helpful, not a textual representation of what you want to have.

Comment: Using `thebibliography` means doing it by hand. Completely by hand. If you want an automatic solution, you should use an external file storing all the relevant information. Christian already mentioned `chapterbib` that is good with the old system using bibtex. It is even easier using the modern package `biblatex` in conjunction with `biber`.

Comment: ok, did not know about these packages..

Answer (score 1):

Biblatex does this very easily. 
First you need to load the package

```
\usepackage[sorting=none, backend=biber, refsection = chapter]{biblatex}
```

**refsection**  is what that separates the references. And you need the backend to be set to "*biber*" if you want the next part to work.

Don't forget to add your .bib file:

```
\addbibresource{library.bib}
```

And finally add the following line at the end of each chapter:

```
\chapter{Chapter One}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
```

If you need to fine tune it more, check out the biblatex [documentation](https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex/)