# Bibliography after each chapter from single bib file

Tags: bibliographies, chapters

I am trying to compile a thesis which has a main.tex file which includes different chapters. I need to have references after each chapter. All the references are in a single .bib file. But when I compile I do not get references list and in place of reference number I get [?].

```
\documentclass[phd,tocprelim]{CU}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}

%\bibliographystyle{plain}
%\bibliographystyle{IEEEbib}

\begin{document}

\include{chapter1/thesis-chapter1}
\include{chapter2/thesis-chapter2}
\include{chapter3/thesis-chapter3}

\end{document}
```

The individual chapters are stored in separate sub-folders. An example for chapter 1 is (All_citations is bibliography file):

```
\chapter{abc}{\label{1}}
\section{Introduction}
...
...
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{All_citations}
```

Thanks

Comment: I found threads similar to your question in the forum:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282779/bibliography-by-chapter

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374546/separate-bibliography-in-each-chapter-and-general-bibliography-in-the-end-with

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229846/different-bibliographies-for-each-chapter-with-shared-references

do you think they can help you?

Comment: Thanks Annie for answering. But I have already seen these threads and unfortunately, they are not solving the issue.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help. Unfortunately it goes beyond my skills. I try to involve more experienced users.

Comment: If the bibliography style is in the main directory, you should use `\bibliography{../All_citations}` --- does `bibtex` find the file or is it complaining?

Comment: did you run bibtex on all the aux-files from the \include commands? You will needed `bibtex thesis-chapter1` (or perhaps `bibtex chapter1/thesis-chapter1`, I have forgotten and didn't check).

Comment: @Rmano I have put bibliography file in the main directory and I use 
`
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{All_citations}
`
in each chapter. bibtex finds the file, creates a .bib file in the directory but it's not creating individual .bib files in each chapter subfolders, although there are .aux files created for each chapter. If there are individual .bib files created for each chapter, then the problem is solved.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am using WinEdt. I am trying to run bibtex on each aux file, but it's not solving issue.

Comment: Hm. You probably should put `All_citations.bib` in your main folder, and use `\bibliography{../All_citations}` in the chapters.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am doing the same i.e. putting All_citations.bib in main folder, and using \bibliography{../All_citations} in the chapters.